# Is there any way to change the directions left to right in Slick carousel ? Default it goes Right to left directions

Tags: javascript, jquery, carousel, slick.js

When I set rtf fasle then the page goes white and when I set slidesToScroll- 1 it also trhoughs same result.

```
$('.demo').slick({
    dots: false,
    slidesToShow: 3,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    infinite: true,
    cssEase: 'linear',

    accessibility:true,

    autoplay:true,
    autoplaySpeed: 3000,

  });
```

Answer (score 2):

Add the rtl option when you initialize slick and set it to true.  You'll also need to set the attribute "dir" to "rtl" for the HTML tag or the parent of the slider.

```
$('.demo').slick({
  dots: false,
  slidesToShow: 3,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  infinite: true,
  cssEase: 'linear',
  accessibility:true,
  autoplay:true,
  autoplaySpeed: 3000,
  rtl: true 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The default for the slideshow is left to right. To enable right to left, you need to set `rtl: true` and then according to the Slick website:

> The HTML tag or the parent of the slider must have the attribute "dir" set to "rtl".

For example:

```
<div dir="rtl">
    <div class="demo">
    ...
    </div>
</div>
```